# Excel VBA - Compile Error - Object Required

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post to this wonderful forum . I am new to VBA and have been writing my first meaningful macro beside doing some practice while learning.

While the WIP code is reproduced below, let me give you a background.

Have a a sheet to calculation investment maturity  based on various inputs like Term of Payment and term of Maturity.

This sheet has all the formule in place to compute the maturity value.

Now on sheet 2, I am creating a matrix structure with a intersection of payment term and term of maturity. For ex combination of 1 Yr of Payment term with maturity ( 1...25) and next Payment term and so on.

I am writing a macro which will pick up the user choice from sheet 1 and then loop the macro in matrix and capture the result and paste it to sheet two .

I am still far away from what i have to achive but got a code in first few line of selecting and setting the payment term and maturity terms

Error is Compile error- Object required. I am not able to figure out what it it. WIP code is reproduced below

```
Private Sub Simulation_Click()
Dim PPT As String
Dim Term As String
MsgBox (" The Programme is starting now")

Set PPT = Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("G2").Value
Set Term = Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value

For PPT = 1 To PPT  
    For Term = 1 To Term  
     ' Do something here  
    Next Term  
Next PPT  

End Sub
```

Please help
EDIT # 1- September 19,2017, 3.10 AM IST
Hi Experts, 
Finally my first VBA code is running . Its slow but its running. One last problem
I have issue in Code line "Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2").Copy Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Sheets("What if").Cells(cols, Rowsh)" where while to source carries the right value( checked in debug Mode) but when it is pasted to target, it is pasted as 0. When I checked the target sheet , somehow it is showing me a formula (= Max( R1C1 :X1Y1). Please note that from where I am copyiong the value ( Source) , its a excel calculation which is arrived as a formula of selecting max of col J . I suspect that code is copying the formula instead of value. Please advice

```js
Option Explicit
Sub macro21()
'MsgBox ("Start")
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim PPT As Integer
Dim Term As Integer
Dim pptrange As Range    ' Address of the Cell where PPT is maintained in Sheet 1
Dim termrange As Range   ' Address of the Cell where Term is maintained in Sheet 1
Dim cols As Integer
Dim Rowsh As Integer

PPT = 3
Term = 5
cols = 3
Rowsh = 3
For i = 1 To PPT

    For j = 1 To Term
        
        Set pptrange = Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2")  ' Set pptrange and termrange locations
        Set termrange = Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3")   ' Set pptrange and termrange locations
        pptrange.Value = i
        termrange.Value = j
        ***Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2").Copy Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Sheets("What if").Cells(cols, Rowsh)***
'        MsgBox ("Value is " & Cells(cols, Rowsh).Value)
        MsgBox ("Value is " & Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2"))
        
        
        If j < Term Then
            cols = cols
            Rowsh = Rowsh + 1
        End If
    Next j
    cols = cols + 1
    Rowsh = 3
Next i

End Sub
```

I have issue in Code line "Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2").Copy Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Sheets("What if").Cells(cols, Rowsh)" where while to source carries the right value( checked in debug Mode) but when it is pasted to target, it is pasted as 0. When I checked the target sheet , somehow it is showing me a formula (= Max( R1C1 :X1Y1). Please note that from where I am copyiong the value ( Source) , its a excel calculation which is arrived as a formula of selecting max of col J . I suspect that code is copying the formula instead of value. Please advice

Comment: For strings, don't use `Set`. Just do `PPT = Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("G2").Value` and `Term = Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value`

Comment: After you get rid of `Set`, change `Dim PPT As String` to `Dim PPT As Long` and  `Dim Term As String` to `Dim Term As Long`.

Comment: Also you need `Worksheets` rather than `Worksheet`

Answer (score 3):

`PPT` is a string so you should use:

```
PPT = ...
```

and not

```
 Set PPT =
```

`Set` is used to assign object variables such as workbooks, worksheets, etc.

Edit: as Jeeped mentioned in his comment you have to change data type. You cannot use string in a loop like that. Change `Term` and `PPT` to `Integer` or `Long`.

Comment: Hi Viktor, I edited your post to change `SET` to `Set` just for clarity, as `SET` in capitals isn't valid syntax (and will be changed by the IDE anyways).

Comment: Hi Victor , dvirony and Jeeped thanks for your quick help . I am surprised with the speed of response itself from you all . I removed the same however   got type mismatch. I thought PPT is a Microsoft object also hence changed my variable names and removed Set as well. Now the error is "Object Doesnt support this property or method

Comment: Private Sub Simulation_Click()  
Dim ppt1 As String  
Dim Term1 As String  
'MsgBox (" Sample Text")  
ppt1 = Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("G2").Value  
Term1 = Workbooks("himanshu.xlsm").Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value  

For i = 1 To ppt1  
    For j = 1 To Term1  
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet("Sheet1").Select
    Range("G2").Value = 1  
    Range("G3").Value = 1  
    Range("c3").Value =  
 Application.Worksheet("Sheet1").Function.Max(Range("N7:n31")).Value  
    Next j  
Next i  

End Sub

Comment: @RaviKantAgarwal As Jeeped commented above, you need to change your variables from `String` to `Long`, as you can't run a loop from 1 to a `String`

Comment: Thanks .. error resolved .. While I am still facing another issue but I will prefer to first bang head on stack overflow so that I can learn and not bother you experts thanks everyone once again !!

Comment: @dwirony As long as the `String` contains a value that can be converted to numeric, you **can** do a loop from 1 to a `String`.  (Not advisable, but is possible.)  E.g. Use `for i=1 to "3" : msgbox i : next` in the Immediate Window.

Comment: @YowE3K Again, another lesson learned for me...  I don't know why I ever doubted VBAs abilities!